# How to keep the values of class variables in jersey web services

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I have created a jersey web service as following,

```
@Path("/myservice")
class MywebService{

private int requestNum = 0;

@GET
@Path("/mymethod")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public void myMethod(){
   System.out.println("Request number : "+(++requestNum));
}

}
```

But each time when I call that myMethod through the web service , I get the request number as 1. Seems like the requestNum always resets to 0. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making it static, i.e.

```
static private int requestNum = 0;
```

The container (Jersey) is responsible for creating instances of your service.  Thus you may have multiple different instances.  Using an instance variable will not work well. The value of that variable will represent the number of times that instance has received a request.

If you use a static variable, that will count the number of requests sent to all instances of your web service class.

Comment: This wouldn't work in multi-tenant environment. The better choice would be to mark the class as singleton (`@Singleton`) and leave the field non-static.